# Blender Fluid Sim, Realistic Vomit?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm trying to use the fluid sim to create a vomit VFX shot for some live action footage I've got. But I'm struggling with getting it look the way I want. So far this is what I've got:

[image]

I'm relatively happy with the way it lands on the floor (except for the jittering), but I'm wanting to improve the way it falls. Currently it just flows too smoothly, where as I'd like it to be more like this:

[image]

So it has more of a 'spraying' and forceful quality to it, where the diameter starts narrow at the source (The mouth) and then it spreads out the further from the mouth it gets.

Any suggestions?

Comment: We should migrate the question again, I think: http://alcohol.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sounds like a matter of tweaking some values like viscosity weight or speed. Otherwise you could try particles instead of fluids.

Comment: I think that you will need to use particles in Fluid mode, perhaps metaballs if you have the ram for it. This will give you the blobbly appearance then render with motion Blur (not sure if that will work with particles though).

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use particles in Fluid mode, perhaps metaballs if you have the ram for it. This will give you the blobby appearance then render with motion Blur. You'll need to duplicate the particle settings and emitter for blur.

[image: color render layer]

[image: vector layer with duplicate emitter]

Use vector blur but you can only use Blender internal for that. Make a normal object particle duplicate of the metaball cascade, on a separate layer. Apply this vector blur to the metaball layer.

[image: render layer 1]

[image: render layer 2]

In the compositor use the 2nd render layer to drive the vector blur.

[image: Send to compositor]

Results with and with out blur, change vector object  scale to suit blur.

[image: results]

You may have to adjust the particle life of the vector object so that you don't get blurring of the floor.

Comment: Nice workflow. However there's an easier way to get motionblur, provided you're rendering with Cycles: Just turn it on in the render panel. No need for renderlayers, and you avoid the artifacts too :)

Comment: Show off :P  but yes Andrew is correct, fluid sim has motion blur as do particles in Cycles now.